# My computer screen turns black after a couple minutes of mining

Tags: gpu

My computer screen - a regular desktop monitor - turns black for few seconds after a couple minutes of mining.

And Msi AfterBurner shows that there isn't a GPU after that happens, and when I disable and renable the GPU, Msi AfterBurner turns to normal.

Comment: If minning? You mean of running? More importantly, is that an actual monitor or a laptop screen?

Comment: @InterLinked it's an actual monitor! I mean of mining but i can explain it you as intensive usage.

Comment: were you trying  overclock the computer? @Djill6

Comment: @Antz No, 100% default setting! it's OC version so it's already overclocked.

Answer (score 1):

> Msi AfterBurner shows that there isn't a GPU after that happens

### Hypothesis 1 (update: wrong guess)

Well, that clinches it I guess. You're boiling your GPU. A reset of course resets the situation - but if you insist, there is the risk of damaging it.

If the GPU has diagnostic hardware that can report temperature and operating status, try and see how mining affects it. It might be the case that the GPU requires extra cooling, or the existing cooler is slightly defective (e.g. loose thermal pad, dried-up thermal grease) so that it can withstand normal usage, but not heavy duty cryptocurrency mining.

### Hypothesis 2

The GPU is not compatible with that particular mining code because of make and model (unlikely: it would stop at once or not even start), or available RAM (possible, but I'd expect they'd check it first thing), or conflicting configuration due to the OS drivers.
What I mean is, while the mining software does its thing leveraging the GPU hardware, the OS also is doing various things that might interfere (the first to come to mind is screen blanking). My own nVIDIA board comes with a control panel with several optimizations, and a couple of them can be turned off "in case of software incompatibilities". I'd check the documentation of both the mining driver and the OS one (and the compatibility matrix if one is available, just in case).

Comment: His GPU could be overheating, but I suppose it could be operating within thermal limits but simply crashing and resetting.

Comment: My gpu is 55 c average and 61 max while mining. And in nvidia website they say that it can take up 94 c (I have a gtx 1050 ti oc)